# Strange remainder problem in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:length(wav)
    if (rem(i,6) ~= 0)
        wav(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

The 6th value in the vector **will** be set to 0 (incorrect), but all the multiples of 6 will remain (which is correct). Strangely, this works correctly if I were to make it rem(i,7) or rem(i,4). Is this a machine precision error? If so, how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: are you sure wav(6) is nonzero before you run the loop?

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this on MATLAB r2010a

```
wav = 1:12;
for i=1:length(wav)
   if (rem(i,6) ~= 0)
       wav(i) = 0;
   end
end
wav
```

produces

> wav =
>        0     0     0     0     0     6     0     0     0     0     0    12

anyway, this code is sure to work and is better MATLAB

```
wav(rem(1:length(wav), 6) ~= 0) = 0;
```

or (likely faster, but may use more memory, both depending on matlab optimizations)

```
wav2 = zeros(size(wav));
wav2(6:6:end) = wav(6:6:end);
```

Comment: Assuming you can afford the space for a second copy of the array, `wav2 = zeros(size(wav)); wav2(6:6:end) = wav(6:6:end);` is probably faster.